# Probability of team winning, if it is trailing by 5 ponts after the first quarter

Tags: probability, statistics

The score difference between home team and away team resembles a normal distribution where the mean is 1.5pts per quarter and the variance is 6 per quarter. What is the probability of the home team winning the game given that the home team is losing by 5pts against the away team after the 1st quarter?

The quarters are assumed independent.

#### Progress

Since it's a normal distribution, $X\sim N(1.5,6)$, if you call $X$ the score difference. If I denote $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$, $X_4$ as the score difference for each quarter, we are finding the conditional probability $P(X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4>5 \mid X_1=-5)$.

Comment: Are the quarters independent?

Comment: so basically since its a normal distribution X~N(1.5,6) if u call x the score difference. If i denote X1,X2,X3,X4 as the score difference for each quarter, we are finding the conditional probability P(X1+X2+X3+X4>5 l X1=-5)

Comment: yeah the quarters are independent

Answer (score 0):

There are three remaining quarters, and the home team scores $S_h \sim N(3 \times 1.5, 3 \times 6)$ more than the away team. So to win the home team needs to score $5$ pts more than the away so you are asking for the probability $p(S_h>5)$, and if you need a continuity correction that should be more like $p(S_h>5.5)$

Comment: what do u mean by continuity correction?

Comment: @ilmck: I don't know what game is being discussed here, but all the games I know have integer numbers of points. But the point difference is being modelled as a continuous RV here so to win it is necessary that a point difference of 6 is achieved. The assumption is that more than 5 under the normal approximation corresponds to more than 5.5 in the continuous domain. See the Wikipedia page for more background: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_correction

Comment: oh my bad.. should've mentioned that it is a basketball match.. sry